# Difference between methods to delete last git commit

Tags: git

Please, what is the difference between `git rebase -i` and `git reset --soft HEAD^` ? what does each one implies in the background ? When to use each one ?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty well covered elsewhere, so I'm going to keep this answer short.

The `git rebase` command is about *copying* (some) commits to new-and-improved commits that we wish to use instead.  Because there are so many options—especially the highly flexible `--interactive` or `-i` option—this gets very complex.

The `git reset` command is itself also complicated, but in this particular usage, is about *discarding* some commits.  If you should subsequently make *new* commits, and if those new commits are in effect new-and-improved copies of the old commits, this reset-and-commit sequence *also* results in copying old commits to new-and-improved commits that we will use instead.

The old `git rebase` was a very fancy shell script that *used* `git reset` followed by `git cherry-pick`.  It has since been rewritten into a very fancy C program that, internally, uses `git reset` followed by `git cherry-pick`: that is, its *external* behavior is mostly the same as before, and while the underlying implementation has been rewritten, it's still very similar.

Hence, depending on *how you use* `git rebase -i`, and *how you use* `git reset --soft`, you can get exactly the same effect.  Use whichever one you prefer, as long as it produces the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @torek for your complete and precise answer.